# Java URI regexp takes too long

Tags: java, regex, filter

I have a servlet filter in my Java app to ensure that users are using up-to-date URI for articles and categories. The problem is, that according to the profiler results this filter takes (self) about 40% of the total time for request (even for simple URI "/") (the inner actions are non-trivial, its dynamic web page with huge menu, article ranking etc.).

```
public class NameFilter implements Filter {

    private ArticleServiceIface articleService;
    private CategoryServiceIface categoryService;
    private UrlRewriteServiceIface urlRewriteService;
    private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?>.*?)/(article|category)/(\\d+)/(?>.*)$");

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(filterConfig.getServletContext());
        articleService = (ArticleServiceIface) ctx.getBean("articleService");
        categoryService = (CategoryServiceIface) ctx.getBean("categoryService");
        urlRewriteService = (UrlRewriteServiceIface) ctx.getBean("urlRewriteService");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(uri);
        String currUri;
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            if (matcher.group(1).equals("article")) {
                Long articleId = Long.valueOf(matcher.group(2));

                ArticleDTO a = articleService.getById(articleId);
                currUri = urlRewriteService.getUrl(a.getId());
            } else {
                Long categoryId = Long.valueOf(matcher.group(2));

                CategoryDTO c = categoryService.getById(categoryId);
                currUri = urlRewriteService.getCategoryUrl(c.getId());
            }
        } else { //does not match neighter article nor category
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        if (currUri.equals(uri)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
            res.setHeader("Location", currUri);
            res.getWriter().close();
        }


    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

I have spend few hours debugging and profiling it, tried many different ways to formulate the regexp, but the results are always the same.

The bottlenect seems to be in the matches method, which gets called resursively and at some point it calls pattern matching iteratively (few thousand times) for some reason...

Thanks for any suggestions.

edit: [Profiler results](http://imageshack.us/f/10/regex.png/) (seems pretty strange to me...according to debugger this should be parsing of URI == "/" )

---

EDIT2: current regexp:

```
 private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?/(article|category)/(\\d+)/.*");
```

the results are still the same. I'll try to measure it with

```
  System.out.print(System.currTimeMillis - time)
```

---

EDIT3: conclusion: its probably netbeans profiler bug...

I have tried this code and URI "/"

```
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        if (matcher.group(1).equals("article")) {
            Long articleId = Long.valueOf(matcher.group(2));

            ArticleDTO a = articleService.getById(articleId);
            currUri = urlRewriteService.getUrl(a.getId());
        } else {
            Long categoryId = Long.valueOf(matcher.group(2));

            CategoryDTO c = categoryService.getById(categoryId);
            currUri = urlRewriteService.getCategoryUrl(c.getId());
        }
    } else { //does not match neighter article nor category
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
        ....
```

The output is allways 0. So it seems to me that netbeans profiler is adding time to this method for some reason.

But thank you all for your help and cooperation, I have learned few regex tricks.

Comment: Can you provide some sample URIs for which it is taking long time? I tried your pattern against `/` and it was pretty quick.

Comment: print the uri. Is it what you thought it would be? Btw, can you explain what valid url:s look like? is /a/b/article/666/hello.txt valid?

Comment: /article/30057/Nim and /category/1012/Grafy or with language mutation prefix /en/article/123/articleName

Comment: Try making the pattern a static attribute as it may create a new object each time, and compiling a pattern takes O(n^m).

Comment: Can you check if [^/]* does your initial match faster than .*? If you expect multiple slashes, it may pay to drop the ^ anchor (which isn't necessary since you are matching .* after the anchor anyway, right?) and just match the part with article|category. Possibly drop your (?>.*)$ as well, for the same reason. When I see ^.* and .*$, I question why those segments are there at all, particularly if those are non-capturing groups... but I may have misinterpreted the intent.

Comment: ups...as I try it now, the prefix version does not work with this version of pattern. But the ones without prefix are valid and working (slowly). The other thing is that its pretty fast when I try it testing loop...but somehow in real world (in the servlet filter) its slow....

Comment: Are you sure that the filter *itself* is not accidentally being called multiple times for a single request?

Comment: ccoakley -- I'll try your suggestion, Robin: according to the profiler its called once per request, Yet another Geek: good point, according to the profiler the problem is in the doFilter method, but this should be changed as well

Comment: Is this statement equivalent (sans having to renumber your groups?): "/(article|category)/(\\d+)/" ... I'm obviously a little lost here because I thought the prefix and suffix were non-capturing groups, so I thought they wouldn't impact the group numbering.

Comment: @malejpavouk unless of course it compiles into a Non-deterministic finite automata then the compilation should be quick, but running the regex should be O(n*m), which can be a lot of time if you get many requests.

Comment: @ccoakley: In this regex `/(article|category)/(\\d+)/` both groups are capturing groups as you can see in my answer as well. To make them non-capturing groups use it like this: `/(?:article|category)/(?:\\d+)/`

Comment: @anubhava: Heh. I know *those* groups are capturing. I meant the initial and final groups in malejpavouk's code. I thought maybe having no quantifier (other than the digit quantifier) would be faster than a non-capturing, reluctant quantifier. Depending on the implementation, the matcher is now just scanning for / instead of tracking the anchor and reluctantly matching . until it finds a /. It made sense in my head. Think about it. It would append whatever it matched to a group, then look ahead to see if there was a /. If not, it would repeat appending. I promise I was trying to be helpful :).

Comment: @ccoakley: I understand what you meant but since OP is trying to match URIs `/en/article/123/articleName` and `/article/123/articleName` therefore `[^/]*` will not work here. If that was not the case I would have used `[^/]*` too which I think is better than `.*?`

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks. My confusion actually stemmed from the original numbering of the groups in the code (2,3 vs 1,2). They've since been corrected (or I'm crazy), which is how I *thought* things should be. That's why I was tripping over myself. But yeah, my `[^/]*` suggestion wasn't good.

Comment: ccoakley: sorry for confusion, I have corrected them, I was testing the regular expression permutations with "/" so it had not used the invalid code. When I found that its bogus, I have repaired the code here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use Lookbehinds in your pattern actually. Following code works for me and in fairly quick time:

```
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*?/(article|category)/(\\d+)/.*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("/category/1012/Grafy");
System.out.println("Matches: " + m.matches());
System.out.println("Group1: " + m.group(1) + ", Group2: " + m.group(2));
System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-l));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Matches: true
Group1: category, Group2: 1012
Time taken: 0
```

### EDIT Try find() intead of matches() like this:

```
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
p = Pattern.compile("/(article|category)/(\\d+)/");
m = p.matcher("/en/article/123/articleName");
System.out.println("Matches: " + m.find());
System.out.println("Group1: " + m.group(1) + ", Group2: " + m.group(2));
System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-l));
```

Comment: My initial code looked almost the same. I have tested your regexp and the results from profiler were as mentioned earlier - takes about 40% of the time. Funny thing is that if I this in a loop I may check about 3 million patterns in a second. So next thing I'll try is if the performance is not biased by the profiler.

Comment: Hmm ok 1 more suggestion. Added code in EDIT section for that. Why are you trying to match full UR if all you care about group1 and group2 only. So I modified the regex and used find() method, can you pls check this.

Comment: The results were allmost the same. I Have edited my question, it seems that this whole thing stems from some bug or my misiterpration of profiler I am using...but thank you for your help and suggestions.